# new line insertion key is not working with `... \n` + `...`

Tags: javascript

I have a stringt that I am trying to create. In between each seperate line, I want to insert a new line tag to make sure that the final message is in three seperate lines seperated by the \n.. this is what I have so far.

```
confirmationMessage = `This action will assign <strong>${stack.name}</strong> to you. \n\n` + 
                      `<strong>IMPORTANT</strong>: This App is currently owned by ${stack.owner.username} and cannot be reassigned to this owner once this action is executed. \n\n` + 
                      `Are you sure you want to take ownership o fthis Dashboard. \n`;
```

I have the \n\n but it is all still rendering in a single line

Comment: Where are you displaying this var?

Comment: Rendering *how*? If this is supposed to be HTML, you should use [`br` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Comment: Where is this string going to be output to? If it's going into an `alert()` or `prompt()`, the escape code will work because those dialogs are processed by the JavaScript runtime. But, if it's destined for an HTML element, then you need to be using `<br>` because that's how you do line breaks in HTML.

Comment: It all depends on where you want to render the output: [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qmcvmz) If it is html you can't use `\n`, you should use proper html tags and CSS to break apart items on the page including text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most-likely because you are passing the string to a parser/runtime where that code is meaningless.

- The HTML parser knows how to parse HTML, but not JavaScript.
- The JavaScript runtime knows how to process JavaScript, but not HTML.

Now, to be clear, no matter where the string winds up, it will have a new line character in it because you established that with a statement that is processed as JavaScript.

If that string containing the new line character winds up being processed by the JavaScript runtime, then those character will be processed correctly, but any HTML will be meaningless and treated like any other string:

```js
alert("The line\nbreak escape codes\nwork here.\nBut, <strong>HTML</strong> doesn't.");
```

But, if you send the string with new line characters in it to the HTML parser,  the new lines are treated like any new line character is in HTML, it's ignored, but HTML is processed.

```js
document.write("The line\nbreak escape codes\nwon't work here.\nBut, <br><strong>HTML</strong> does.");
```

```html
<div>
You
don't
see
each
word
on
its
own
line
here
because
new
lines
in
HTML
are ignored.
</div>
```